# Como hacer un loop en .gs para detalles de registros

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un formulario personalizado el cual requiere que construya una cantidad N de inputs y los almacene en un spreadsheet, cada dato debe registrarse como una lista según el número de inputs creados. Es posible hacerlo desde el main para que registre solo la cantidad de inputs creados (tengo un límite de 10 pero no quiero que almacene registros null)

```
function processRef(e){ 
  for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
   var sNroref[i] = e.nroref[i];
  }

  var hojaDatos = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Refs'); 
  var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

  for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,1).setValue(sNroref[i]);
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }
}
```

Hasta ahora solo he logrado que funcione esto:

```
function processReferenciaDetalle(e){
  var sMtempo = new Date();
  var sMTpRec = e.MTpRec;
  var sFecent = e.fecent;
  var sNroref1 = e.nroref1;
  var sNroref2 = e.nroref2;
  var sNroref3 = e.nroref3;
  var sNroref4 = e.nroref4;
  var sNroref5 = e.nroref5;
  var sDirent = e.dirent;

  var hojaDatos = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Referencias'); 
  var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,1).setValue(sMtempo);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,2).setValue(sMTpRec);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,3).setValue(sFecent);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,4).setValue(sNroref1);
  hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,5).setValue(sDirent);
  if (sNroref2!=""){
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+2,1).setValue(sMtempo);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+2,2).setValue(sMTpRec);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+2,3).setValue(sFecent);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+2,4).setValue(sNroref2);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+2,5).setValue(sDirent);
  }
  ...
  if (sNroref5!=""){
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+5,1).setValue(sMtempo);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+5,2).setValue(sMTpRec);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+5,3).setValue(sFecent);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+5,4).setValue(sNroref5);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+5,5).setValue(sDirent);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Con un loop tendría un codigo mas limpio pero no logro que funcione.

Comment: Karen, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,

Comment: @Jorgesys La pregunta que hago es tan concreta como puede ser, en realidad necesito saber si se puede hacer porque no he encontrado informacion al respecto, gracias por tu comentario, agradecere que la liberes para que al menos si no es asi pueda encontrar otra forma de resolver el problema que tengo. PD. Ya tengo 4 medallas no es que la este contando pero .....

Comment: En el sitio puedes encontrar ayuda de otros desarrolladores de la comunidad, pero te he sugerido en varias ocasiones realizar el [tour]  para entender como funciona el sitio y formular tu pregunta en base a [ask], en este caso agrega lo que has intentado o un [mcve].

Comment: Karen, mas alla de las medalla y que Jorge parezca pesado, el [tour] es importante porque no funcionamos como otros sitios, y ni siquiera tenemos las mismas reglas que SO en ingles. Ademas noto que tenes 5 preguntas con 0 respuestas aceptadas. Cual es el problema de esas preguntas? aceptar respuestas o pedir aclaraciones es muy importante. Y mas alla que la pregunta sea clara, aca yo te preguntaria. Lo probaste? que paso?

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas las función `processRef(e)`? ¿Cuál es el valor u objeto asignado a `e`? Si te devuelve un error indica textualmente cuál es este.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es el loop en si, sino como se hace referencia a los datos recibidos del formulario, hasta ahora la solución mas factible ha sido guardar las referencias en un array, lo que permite un código mas limpio y corto.

```
function processReferenciaDetalle(e) {
  var sMTpRec = e.MTpRec;
  var sFecent = e.fecent;
  var sDirent = e.dirent;

  var hojaDatos = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Referencias'); 
  var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

  var navInput = [e.nroref1, e.nroref2, e.nroref3, e.nroref4, e.nroref5];
  for(var i = 0; i < e.nrosac; i++){ //Cantidad de registros esperada
   var sNroref = navInput[i];
   var ind = i+1;
   if (sNroref != ""){
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+ind,1).setValue(sMtempo);
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+ind,2).setValue(sMTpRec);
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+ind,3).setValue(sFecent);
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+ind,4).setValue(sNroref);
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+ind,5).setValue(sDirent);
   }    
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

> ¿Es posible hacer un loop en el main de Google Apps Script?

Entendiendo por "main" un archivo de código del lado del servidor (extensión .gs), dado que en Google Apps Script es posible usar la mayoría de la sentencias de ECMAScript 5 por lo que puedes usar, todos las que se mencionan en [Bucles e iteración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Bucles_e_iteraci%C3%B3n) de Mozilla Developer Network.

> Las sentencias para bucles disponibles en JavaScript son:
>
> - sentencia for
> - sentencia do...while
> - sentencia while
> - sentencia label
> - sentencia break
> - sentencia continue
> - sentencia for...in
> - sentencia for...of

En lo personal no he probado label.

Ejemplo

El siguiente ejemplo imprime un texto en los registros del Editor de proyectos de Google Apps Script

```
function ejemploFor() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    Logger.log('Iteración número ' + (i + 1));
  }
}
```

Resultado:

```
[18-02-24 19:31:12:060 CST] Iteración número 1
[18-02-24 19:31:12:061 CST] Iteración número 2
[18-02-24 19:31:12:061 CST] Iteración número 3
[18-02-24 19:31:12:062 CST] Iteración número 4
[18-02-24 19:31:12:063 CST] Iteración número 5
```

Comment: estuve tratando de crear una sentencia simple for en un .gs pero me da problemas con toda la sintaxis, asumí que no se escribía igual pero he trabajado con if igual como lo haría en el script de html y no me da problemas. Preguntar aquí es lo ultimo que hago porque si bien es cierto q su capacidad para encontrar soluciones es muy buena, la capacidad para interactuar es pésima. Sin intención de ofender pero ya lei el manual de como preguntar y en este sitio también aceptan preguntas "estupidas" si no tienen respuestas ok pero si las tienen aunq no les gusten dejen que los demas ayuden.

Comment: En relación a lo que has intentado agrégalo a tu pregunta incluyendo un [mcve]. No me queda claro si la crítica es hacia mí o hacia el sitio en cualquier caso ahora ya cuentas con suficiente reputación para participar en [meta] donde sería más apropiado los comentarios con respecto al modelo del sitio ya sea críticas constructivas o solicitud de orientación y/o aclaraciones sobre su funcionamiento.